# How do I troubleshoot a P0400 EGR?

Tags: egr

2011 Ford Escape V-6. 130,000 mi.
My daughter lives 4 hours away. She dropped by a couple weeks ago with a p0400 EGR code. And water pump problems. I didn’t have time to do proper diagnosis, so I shotgunned and replaced electric EGR valve. I cleared codes and it was good for over a week. Now the P0400 is back. She’s visiting again another short one and I would like some help to quickly diagnose this. All I know what to do is
1: make sure the exhaust tube is not leaking.
2: check connector
3: make sure gasket is sealing.
4: activate egr with scanner and watch map sensor?
I read #4 online. What else am I missing?

Comment: Some models have an egr tube (channel) that gets clogged and needs cleaned out.

Comment: Thank you. I had to remove this to change valve and it was clear, but it's probably a good idea to double-check as I was in a hurry.

Comment: The possible plug which Moab is describing can occur anywhere along the way where the exhaust enters the EGR tract, through the valve, and where it gets to the intake. It's good to take some brake clean or carb cleaner and hose it down whether it looks plugged or not.

Comment: Thank you. It's a single 1\2" tube that's pipe threaded into the exhaust manifold that goes directly to the valve. I'll douse it good.

Comment: There is another passage that goes into the intake manifold, this may be clogged.

Comment: The EGR bolts to a bracket. The bracket holds a tube that goes into the intake and takes a 90 degree turn. That's where the clog was. The first time I went into this I neglected to look at this. Too much in a hurry with time restraints. Would have saved some trouble if I would have taken this next step the first time. Thanks for all the great input.